# What's the opposite (term) to 'cleavage'?

Tags: word-request

Indeed, it is not a taboo subject anymore! In fact, I frequently read about it in news papers mentioning this as dressing sense or beauty of a woman (I guess there are competitions as well).

Whatever--a dressing sense--or naturally forming 'deep cut', some have it well-defined, others simply show its absence.

Now there could be two opposites in this case and I am searching for both those terms.

> A) What's the opposite term for **the word 'cleavage'** - a woman with *absence* of cleavage (*flat* or *no cleavage* does not convince me).

AND...

> B) What's the term that **describes opposite of cleavage itself** - *[cleavage](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cleavage)* is *the space between the organs that can be seen **above a dress** but then some dresses (not uploading a picture here to keep this site graphically clean) show them from the bottom i.e. **below the top** (opposite direction)? What's the term for that? *Cleavage from Bottom?* *'Bottom Cleft'* - no way. No word with *[bottom (#7)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bottom_1)* can prevent ambiguity here.

Comment: downvoting a question? May I know the reason? Do I need to clarify anything?

Comment: Perhaps, *Cleavageless* or *Shapeless* :)

Comment: @GATA Eh! Found it on Google Book! +1 The sentence reads: *I was back in my own clothes, makeup free and cleavageless. I had gone out on stage in front of ...*

Comment: @GATA I take it! But then trust me, there's a **sure term** for the second question there. I had read it but forgot. It was very nicely termed.

Comment: I would be surprised if I find out there is a word for it :)

Comment: There is... in fact I just need some push... it's in my mind but not coming to my tongue :( If not term, there's a phrase.

Comment: @GATA It's **underboob**, just putting here as you were curious and the notification comes in your inbox! :) Not just that, there are *innerboob, sideboob* as well. Very well searched by chapka.

Comment: Fashion industry's glossary is getting bigger and bigger day after day :) I didn't expect even a word but it was actually Comprehensively defined :-)

Comment: It doesn’t exactly answer your question, but the term “décolletage” is borrowed from French by English speakers in order to discuss the neck-down exposure of some garments. In my experience, this word is used to refer to the area of a woman’s chest that is exposed by a garment, usually _not_ referring to cleavage. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9colletage) indicates that décolletage is not necessarily exclusive of cleavage, however.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Thanks Tyler. It's good to know this word as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A woman lacking cleavage" is not the opposite of "cleavage," it's the opposite of "a woman showing cleavage," which there is not a single word for, either.

Not every word--even a word that is "a feature of something"--has a single word you can point to as its "opposite." What is the opposite of "redheaded"? It's "not redheaded." Similarly, the opposite of "showing cleavage" is "not showing cleavage."

Cleavage, as it's used in American English at least, is also not an inherent feature of a woman's body; it's an effect produced in large part by the way the woman is dressed. It doesn't matter how a person's body is shaped; if she is wearing a turtleneck sweater, she is not going to show any "cleavage."

As for cleavage shown at the bottom of the breasts, impeccable source Jezebel calls it "[underboob](http://jezebel.com/beyond-cleavage-the-golden-age-of-innerboob-sideboob-563316791)."

Comment: BINGO! It's underboob. Thanks a ton buddy. You helped me getting into comfort zone now. This was in some unknown corner of my brain which was making me uncomfortable!

Comment: BTW, may I know how did you search it (I want to know the search term) or you already knew the term?

Answer (score 1):

I think cleavage is simply a thing. It is the space between a woman's breasts. I don't think it has an opposite. It is like asking what the opposite of "pencil" is.

Cleavageless seems kind of constructed to me. I would understand it if I read it or if I heard it in conversation, but I don't think it is technically a word and I don't think you would find it in many dictionaries.

This happens sometimes. Native speakers will add suffixes to certain words and just create their own words when they cannot think of a better word. I've seen this with -less, -ful, -y, and several other suffixes.

Comment: It's a feature of something and thus can have some term opposite to that. Also, there's another concern as well. If we accept cleavage as a cleavage, what about its opposite in terms of its exposure? A cleft seen from the bottom?